# Symfony Doctrine: When flushing a large amount of entities, how to handle a situation with possible database changes in the background?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, transactions

Not having a lot of experience with Doctrine I would like to know how to solve the following problem the best way.

This is a code within an E-Mail reminder function:

```
foreach($this->entityRepository->getEntityExpirationReminderCandidates($reminderDay) as $entity) {
    if($entity instanceof Entity) {
        try {
            $sent = $this->entityStatusUpdateMailer->sendUpdateFetchUser($entity);
            if(!$sent) {
                throw new MailException("Due to misconfiguration an email could not be sent.");
            }
        } catch(Throwable $exception){
            // unable to send status update email
            $sent = false;
        }
        if($sent) {
            $setReminderSent($entity);
            $this->entityRepository->persist($entity);
        }
    }
}
$this->entityRepository->flushEntities();
$this->entityRepository->clearEntities();
```

Now lets assume that the call to ***getEntityExpirationReminderCandidates*** can return up to 5000 entities, that means that loop may run for some seconds. If any of the entities now is changed or deleted in the database in the background will Doctrine still be able to perform the rest of the transaction? It does not feel good to flush each entity on its own within the loop for performance reasons.

I want to avoid that the whole transaction fails though just because a certain entity is deleted in the background while the loop runs. I am curious what could happen and how Doctrine will handle this?

NOTE for better understanding: Afaik on `->flushEntities()` a `COMMIT;` transaction is running which basically means all or nothing.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html#usage

Comment: I think that it depend of the isolation level that you can set for that transaction, granting the espected atomicity on your large operation